# Loading pickle weights in JAX throws assertion error

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pickle, jax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDA3f.png)

I am trying to load weights from a saved pickle file. It throws an unspecific assertion error.

I was expecting that I can retrieve the opt_state from the saved file. I am not using flax or any other framework.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll have better luck getting your question answered if you paste the text of your code and error rather than uploading a screenshot. You should be able to edit your question to add this pasted text. For more tips, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask